# Remove column sep between longtable and a tabular insides

Tags: tables

when I created a tabular inside longtable, there is a space between them. How can I remove that space? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1.75cm, bmargin=0.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|} 
\hline
X & \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
A& B \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to (a) change the structure of the `longtable` environment, as shown in the second table below, and (b) omit the first and last `\hline` instructions from the `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1.75cm, bmargin=0.5cm, hmargin=1.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|} 
\caption{Before}\\
\hline
X & \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|c@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}c@{}} 
\caption{After}\\
\hline
X & \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
A & B \\
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, to address the query the OP posted in follow-up comments: If columns 2 and 3 of the outer `longtable` are of type `p{2cm}` rather than `c`, and if the two columns of the inner `tabular` environment are also of type `p{2cm}`, your objective may be achieved with the following code:

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
\hline 
X & X & X \\ 
X & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{%
       \begin{tabular}[t]{p{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
       A & B \\ 
       \end{tabular}} \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

I must confess to not understanding what this setup -- replacing columns of type `p{2cm}` with identically-typed column -- is supposed to achieve, except maybe to prevent page breaks happening to the material that's inside the inner `tabular` environment. (However, that shouldn't happen anyway, as `longtable` doesn't permit page breaks within "cells".)

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I've just got a new problem. When I add another row, the separate lines of tabular is not align with the ones of longtable.

Comment: @minmin - Does replacing `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}` with `\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}` work? (I assume you want top-alignment.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain clearly. The problem happened when I add multicolumn and then create new tabular inside it.  Here is the code                                    \documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1.75cm, bmargin=0.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}p{2cm}@{}|p{2cm}|} 
\caption{After}\\
\hline
X & X & X \\ 

X & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
A & B \\
\end{tabular}} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}

Comment: @minmin - You appear to be mixing fixed-width `p{2cm}` columns with variable-width `c` columns. What exactly are you trying to achieve? (I assume it's *not* typesetting Xs, As, and Bs...) Maybe you should post a new query, as the new setup is potentially quite different from the one in the current posting?